# Why is a system composed of two Bell-LaPadula-secure systems not necessarily Bell-LaPadula-secure?

Tags: bell-lapadula

In my lecture notes, it says that a system composed of two Bell-LaPadula-secure systems is not necessarily Bell-LaPadula-secure? Is there an example that demonstrates this concept?

Answer (score 1):

The Discretionary Security Property is an access matrix that is linked to that particular system.

When you combine two systems, you must rigorously review the access matrix that will be assigned to the new composite system.

In cases where the classifications and compartments do not align perfectly, careful consideration is necessary to maintain a level of security that is equivalent or better.

In addition, there is the possibility that the scope of information available in each system is different. The aggregation of information possible after the systems are combined may exceed the intended security level, even if the original classifications and compartments aligned perfectly. The original access matrix was based on assumptions about what the information that the system would hold, and those assumptions are no longer true.

The original Bell-LaPadula model does not address either of these concerns, but any modern efforts should be capable of addressing the issues with some planning.